# PHP MySQL query select DISTINCT but display Limited Rows order by date

Tags: php, mysql, database, distinct

I need help with DISTINCT. I would like to display Distinct row but display only latest tow row order by date (col3)

Example this table from database:

```
+----+-----+------------+
|col1|col2 |col3        |
+----+-----+------------+
|A   |one  |1-jul-2013  |
|A   |two  |2-jul-2013  |
|A   |three|3-jul-2013  |
|A   |four |4-jul-2013  |
|A   |five |5-jul-2013  |
|B   |one  |1-jul-2013  |
|B   |two  |2-jul-2013  |
|B   |three|3-jul-2013  |
|B   |four |4-jul-2013  |
|B   |five |5-jul-2013  |
|B   |six  |6-jul-2013  |
|B   |seven|7-jul-2013  |
|B   |eight|8-jul-2013  |
+----+-----+-----+

$query = mysql_query('select * from table1 ORDER BY col3 DESC');
$results = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $col1= $row['col1'];

    // This is basically grouping your rows by col1
    if(!isset($results[$col1]))
        $results[$col1] = array();
    $results[$col1][] = $row;
}

echo "<tr>";

foreach($results as $col1=> $rows) {

    echo "<td>".$col1."</td>";

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo "<td>".$row['col2']."</td>";
    }

    echo"</tr>";
}
```

I need some modification on it.. i want distinct and show only latest 2 row

I would like the display to look like this :

```
A  |one  |two 

B  |one  |two
```

Comment: Add "LIMIT 2" to the end of your query?

Comment: spend some time on formatting your question properly.

Comment: This is MySQL. I see no dates, only strings and integers

Answer (score 0):

Following is the query,

```
$query = mysql_query('select DISTINCT `column name` from table1 ORDER BY col3 DESC LIMIT 2');
```

Comment: Chosen column, outside of stuff like COUNT(DISTINCT X), has nothing to do with distinct. DISTINCT gives distinct result records using all fields of the results.

Comment: DISTINCT is not work on it.. this is grouping method and If i add LIMIT 2 its show only 2 Group.. i want all group Like A B C D E F G but if we have 5 Record of A. we fetch only two records order my date